# Set of points between two parabolas

Tags: general-topology

This is probably an easy question, but I can't get the hang of it. I can't show that $g(x,y)=y^2+x$ is continuous, where $g$ maps $\mathbb{R}\times \mathbb{R}$ to $\mathbb{R}$. Some hints would be appreciated. Assume the standard topology for both spaces. Basically I need to show the preimage of an open interval is open. Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 0):

Set y to zero then its clear that $g(x)$ goes from $Rx0$ to $R$ add back in a changing y value without changing the range

Answer (score 0):

Hint : prove that if $f,g : \mathbb R^2 \to \mathbb R$ are continous functions, then $f + g$ is also a continous function.

Also notice that a map $f : \mathbb R^2 \to \mathbb R$ is continous (i.e the preimage of an open subset is open) if and only if for any sequence $(x_n,y_n) \to (x,y)$ then $f(x_n,y_n) \to f(x,y)$.